# piwik, how to get data per sub-domain?

Tags: matomo

I have many sub-domains and I want to event data for each sub-domain.
what I did is execute HTTP request like this, for each sub-domain:

```
/? 
idSite=6& 
token_auth=out-outh-token& 
format=json& 
date=2014-10-13%2C2014-10-14& 
expanded=1& 
segment=eventCategory%3D%3Dgoals%3BpageUrl%3D%40some-sub-domain& 
method=Events.getCategory& 
module=API& 
period=range
```

which works fine for development, but as I execute many HTTP requests, they (the requests) start to time out.
so I added waits every time it encountered a timeout, what made it slow...
is there a way to get all this data in one request?
is there a way to better handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

How many subdomains do you have? Please consider adding those segments in the segment editor and set them to "pre-archived" (I assume you have cron archiving set up).

It's normal that such queries timeout. Piwik by default processes such requests (needs to iterate through all the reports with segment applied in the "where" clause).